# How get file path from std::ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, file, absolute-path

I open a file using `std::ifstream`.

I may open file using relative path (`file.txt`) or absolute path (`C:\test\file.txt`).

As I am passing a string as the file name, I dont know whether it is relative or absolute path.

Can anybody tell me how to get absolute path after file has been successfully open using 
`std::ifstream` ?

e.g.:

```
std::ifstream file(strFile); // strFile is "file.txt" or "C:\test\file.txt"
```

I want to get the absolute path after the file was open successfully.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you doing a console app or are you using a framework to have some sort of user interface (UI)?

Answer (score 23):

You can't, `std::ifstream` does not store this information.

What you *can* do, however, is:

1. use process' current working directory to compose the absolute path yourself, or
2. use a library like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library to transform between relative and absolute paths.

   ```
   boost::filesystem::path abs_path = boost::filesystem::complete("./rel/path");
   std::string abs_path_str = abs_path.string();
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The fstream classes have no functionality for accessing or processing the name used to open the file with, and the C++ Standard Library has no filename processing functions - you will have to write the code yourself, or use a third-party library or operating system-supplied functions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible for a std::fstream.  I did it for a FILE * on Windows (in a non-portable way).  See [from file object to file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046515/from-file-object-to-file-name/2048730#2048730).

Have you considered extending the ifstream with your own class that remembers the file name?

Comment: It would be helpful if the person who voted down this 5 year old answer left a comment explaining what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just declare
std::string strFile;
in an external scope to be accessible in other scopes as well , something like global variable