# Read File Descriptor Table programmatically in C

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

A child process created using fork() call inherits file descriptor table of its parent process. In my child process, I would like know about the file descriptors that it inherited from its parent process (and their respective file pointers or the file names that it is pointing at). I know that that entries can be stored in variables that the child process inherits. But, I would like to know about a programming way to retrieve this information.

Comment: The programming way to retrieve it is to do exactly what you said you already know you can do: store the name and their associated file pointers in a relational construct that can be referred to by the child process after the fork. Anything outside of that is [highly platform-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046515/from-file-object-to-file-name) at best, and not possible more than likely.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this as Linux, you can look in `/proc/self/fd/*` and `/proc/self/fdinfo/*`.  To get the filename, for example, you can use [`readlink`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189582).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all file descriptors starting from 0 and pass them to `fstat`.